# Running pyomo examples in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, pyomo

I know that some examples from the Pyomo book can be run from Anaconda company prompt, eg. by the command “runef -m ReferenceModel.py” for the farmer example.

I would like to run the examples within the Spyder IDE. Spyder doesn’t recognise any of the code. For example, I get the following error message ‘from pyomo.core import *’ used; unable to detect undefined names

How can I run the examples within Spyder? I am not sure if adding a line 
pyomo solve my_model.ph my_data.dat —-solver=‘glpk’ at the end of the script would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've set up your abstract model, you can instantiate it with data using:

```
data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename="my_data.dat", model=my_model)
```

Then you can solve in Spyder and present results with the following:

```
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

opt = pyomo.environ.SolverFactory('glpk')
instance = model.create_instance(data)

opt.solve(instance)
instance.display()
```

References:

(1) https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1376827

(2) https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_models.html